# Pressing enter just makes another line in input in C++

Tags: c++

Hey want the user to enter some message in C++ console. but when the user press enter it will creat a new line in the console. and when the user press esc i want the program to end

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string message;

cout << "Please enter the message you want to print: \n\n";
cout << "Message: ";

getline(cin, message);

while(cin.get() == '\n') {
    cout << "\n";
}

cout << " " << message;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: submit your code in question

Comment: This is an OS-dependent question.

Comment: Please see [ask].

Comment: just use `getchar`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 1):

Dependent on your OS,

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int flag=0;

    std::cout<<"Please press enter key\n";

    while(flag==0){
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN))
        {
            flag=1;
            std::cin.ignore();
        }
    }

    std::cout<<"good bye\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Same as escape key, VK_ESCAPE.